# Actualizar datos de una columna en JTable sin afectar a los demas datos

Tags: java, java-swing, jframe, jtable

¿Hay manera de Actualizar los datos de una columna mediante un botón? esto sin afectar los demas datos de otras columnas.

Como se ve en la imagen el propósito es cambiar todos los datos de la columna "TERMINO" a un dato diferente:

[image: Tabla]

De antemano una disculpa si es muy sencillo, soy algo inexperto en java

Comment: Necesitas cambiar todos los datos de esa columna o solo algunos?, y desde donde vas a recuperar el nuevo valor que se va a ingresar(la misma tabla, desde un mensaje `JOptionPane`, o variable) cual es tu idea, si contestas estas preguntas tal vez te pueda ayudar con una respuesta más acertada.

Answer (score 0):

has un for para recorrer la filas del jtable y el indice de la columna lo pones en duro osea como veo la imagen (el indice seria 2, contando de cero).

```
for(int i = 0; completas....) {//para recorrer la filas de jtabla
    nombreJtable.setValueAt(Object aValue, int rowIndex, int columnIndex)
}
```

columnIndex = (depende de que columna quieres cambiar)

Comment: Además de crear el botón, asignarle un evento de actionPerformed (por ejemplo) y teclear dicho código (incompleto, por cierto) en él.